# Able to Receive file but file not storing in Android External Storage

Tags: android, smack

I am creating Xmpp application using SMACK api and Spark for test. 
I am able to send from Spark but I cannot see Any Directory and File created in android gallery.

[image]

I log the method `incoming.getAmountWritten()` and it is giving me

```
07-27 21:00:58.789: V/Receiving Status ...(17652): 208861
```

It means I have got the file and now I have to write on physical storage. May be there is problem with my android code.

Please find **Android Code**

```
@Override
        public void fileTransferRequest(final FileTransferRequest fileRequest) {
            final File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            final File folder = new File(dir+ "/illuxplain/");
            boolean success = true;
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                success = folder.mkdir();
            }

            if (success) {
                Thread receiving = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        IncomingFileTransfer incoming = fileRequest.accept();
                        Log.v("Receiving File Name", incoming.getFileName());
                        File file = new File(folder, incoming.getFileName());
                        try {
                            incoming.recieveFile(file);
                            while (!incoming.isDone()) {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.e("", e.getMessage());
                                }
                                if (incoming.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {
                                    Log.e("ERROR!!! ", incoming.getError() + "");
                                }
                                if (incoming.getException() != null) {
                                    incoming.getException().printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            Log.v("Receiving Status ... ",""+incoming.getAmountWritten());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });

                receiving.start();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Directory Not Created");
            }
        }

    }
```

When I go to gallery and see if I got the file. I see no directory created and of course no file.

Comment: What about the class `IncomingFileTransfer` , where you are writing the file ??

Comment: IncomingFileTransfer from smack api I am receiving incoming file from spark

Answer (score -1):

You need to write the data into the file. Here is an example to code to write the data in to the file

```
    File file = new File(folder, incoming.getFileName());   


    String string = "Hello world!";
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
      outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
      outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
      outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Where I use incoming.receiveFile(file) method?

Comment: what is the purpose of the method..what is the funcationalty??

Comment: My bad, Sorry.. I should mention in question. Editing my question

Comment: https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/filetransfer/IncomingFileTransfer.html#recieveFile(java.io.File) this documentation of smack api, provide little detail about IncomingFileTransfer class

Comment: Did you set the `STORAGE_PERMISSION`

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> this permission I have set

Comment: Is that giving any errror..you are catching all excpetions. App wont crash if it got any exception It will go to that line `Log.v("Receiving Status ... ",""+incoming.getAmountWritten());`

Comment: Yup.. I mention this in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84394/discussion-between-bgorle-and-mubeen).